# Not transactional spring methods writing anyway

Tags: spring, transactions

I have a main in a project who instantiate a DAO called AnagrafePfDaoImpl (italian/english names).
This DAO has these declarations:

```
<bean id="AnagrafePfDaoImpl"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager">
        <ref bean="transactionManager" />
    </property>
    <property name="target">
        <ref bean="anagraficaDAOTarget" />
    </property>
    <property name="proxyTargetClass" value="true" />
    <property name="transactionAttributes">
        <props>
            <prop key="insert*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED, ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED</prop>
            <prop key="update*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED, ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED</prop>
            <prop key="merge*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED, ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED</prop>
            <prop key="salva*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED, ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED</prop>
            <prop key="delete*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED, ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED</prop>
            <prop key="search*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED, ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED</prop>
            <prop key="find*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED, ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED,readOnly</prop>
            <prop key="get*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED,readOnly</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I assumed that if I call a method in AnagrafePfDaoImpl called doStuff() in which I do, for example, an update, this would not have any effect unless called from a method which have its own transaction. But I'm wrong because if I call doStuff() from my main class (which has no declarations), the method actually writes in my DB. Can you please tell me why? Sorry for my english.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your component is defined similar to the following:

```
@Component
public class AnagraficaDAOTarget {

  @Autowired
  DataSource dataSource;

  public long doStuff(String message) throws Exception {
    long id;
    try(Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
      id = getId(connection);
      try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("insert into comment (id, message) values (?, ?)")) {
        statement.setLong(1, id);
        statement.setString(2, message);
        int count = statement.executeUpdate();
        if (count != 1) {
          throw new Exception("expected one row insert, actual: " + count);
        }
      }
    }
    return id;
  }
}
```

Then the Connection is in auto commit mode, so even if doStuff is not transactional, the changes are still applied to the database.

Comment: Yes, but does not that mean that the transaction is created if the method name start with "update"? My method is called doStuff so it shouldn't create a transaction. That's what I thought at least.

Comment: The jdbc connection might have autoCommit set to true.

Comment: Do you think it's fine to declare the method "doStuff" like this
 <prop key="doStuff*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED,readOnly</prop>
(read only) so to actually write it has to be called from a method which has its own not read only transaction?

Comment: No, readOnly is used only when you use select, not update, insert or delete.

Comment: If you are trying to delay the commit to a later time, you can make the calling method transactional.

Comment: I'll do that, but I also wanted to assure that only a transactional method calling mine would actually write. If I make the calling method transactional will work for THAT calling method. Not in general.

Comment: In this case you could mark the doStuff method as PROPAGATION_MANDATORY, so it will throw an exception if it is called without an active transaction.